# How to delete data from child and also its image data on server if we delete parent in nodejs mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, amazon-s3

I have a database in which the user is a parent and it has some child documents child document has image data too and those images are stored in the AWS s3 bucket. I used MongoDB middleware remove to perform cascade delete. If I delete parents then the data from the child table is also deleted but the image data remains in the s3 bucket. How can I implement the logic that image data should also be deleted from the server on deleting the parent? I also wrote AWS SDK delete APIs but how can I connect them to the parent document?

// This is the parent delete API

```
function user_delete(req, res, next) {
    User.findOne({ _id: req.params.id })
        .then(user => {
            if (!user) {
                return next('The user you requested could not be found.')
            }

            Child.remove({ userId: user._id }).exec(); //using middleware to delete child when parent deleted
            user.remove();
            return res.status(200).send('User deleted');
            
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
            if (err.kind === 'ObjectId') {
                return next(res.status(404).send({
                    success: false,
                    message: "User not found with id "
                }));
            }
            return next(res.status(500).send({
                success: false,
                message: "Error retrieving User with id "
            }));
        });
};
router.delete('/delete/:id', user_delete);
```

// Delete function for aws SDK delete a file from s3

```
function deleteFileStream(fileKey, next) {
    const deleteParams = {
        Key: fileKey,
        Bucket: bucket_name,
    }
    s3.deleteObject(deleteParams, (error, data) => {
        next(error, data)
    })
}
exports.deleteFileStream = deleteFileStream;
```

// Child delete document API

```
function delete_child(req, res, next) {
    Child.findById(req.params.id)
        .then(child => {
            if (!child) {
                return next(res.status(404).send({
                    success: false,
                    message: "child not found with id " + req.params.id
                }));
            }

            // deleting the images of questions also if it has image
            if(question.file !== '') {
                const url_parts = url.parse(question.file, true);
                const datas = url_parts.pathname.split('getImage/')
                const filekey = datas.pop();
                console.log(filekey);
                deleteFileStream(filekey); // calling the delete function
            }
            child.remove()
            return res.send({
                success: true,
                message: "child successfully deleted!"
            });
        }).catch(err => {
            if (err.kind === 'ObjectId' || err.name === 'NotFound') {
                return res.status(404).send({
                    success: false,
                    message: "child not found with id " + req.params.id
                });
            }
            return res.status(500).send({
                success: false,
                message: "Could not delete question with id " + req.params.id
            });
        });
}
router.delete('/delete/:id', delete_child);
```

If I call the child API the image is also deleted from the server as I am deleting it but if I delete the parent the child is deleted but not the image. Can anybody tell me, please? I am struggling with this use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can collect all image paths from the child before deleting Parent. After deleting the parent, you have to call S3 delete API and provide those paths to delete.

```
const deleteS3Files = async (imageKeys: []) => {
    const bucketParams = {
        Bucket: "BUCKET_NAME",
        Delete: {
            Objects: imageKeys
        }
    };
    try {
        const data = await s3Client.send(new DeleteObjectsCommand(bucketParams));
        return data; // For unit tests.
        console.log("Success. Object deleted.");
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error", err);
    }
};

async function user_delete(req, res, next) {
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ _id: req.params.id });
        if (!user) {
            return next('The user you requested could not be found.')
        }
        //Collect all the child image paths from the collection.
        //create an array of key objects like imageKeys.
        //const imagesKeys : [{Key: imageKey1}, {Key: imageKey2}....];
        const imageKeys = [];

        await Child.remove({ userId: user._id }).exec();
        await user.remove().exec();

        //After deleting data, you can remove the images
        await deleteS3Files(imageKeys)

        return res.status(200).send('User deleted');
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(err)
        if (err.kind === 'ObjectId') {
            return next(res.status(404).send({
                success: false,
                message: "User not found with id "
            }));
        }
        return next(res.status(500).send({
            success: false,
            message: "Error retrieving User with id "
        }));
    }
    router.delete('/delete/:id', user_delete);
```